# Why does Xcode5 keeps stacking 20 points in my view controller when switching to iOS6 view and then back to iOS7 many times?

Tags: ios, xcode5, viewcontroller

Why does xcode5 add 20points in my view controller after switching between view as `"iOS 6.1 or earlier" and "iOS 7.0 or later"`.

An example is I have a `view controller with 45pts` as its height. Every time I switch how the view controller is viewed `(between iOS 6 and iOS 7), the height increases by 20`. My view controller is on a storyboard.

For your reference, here's the current setup:

```
Size: Freeform
Orientation: Portrait
Status Bar: Inferred
Top Bar: Inferred
Bottom Bar: Inferred
```

It only seems to affect view controllers when their size is Freeform. Upon checking on my project. It doesn't seem to have any effect when run on.

**UPDATE regarding if it's a bug or not**

My issue is why does xcode increase my freeform vc's height every time I switch view from iOS 6 view mode to and iOS 7 view mode and then switch it back and again and again. I am going to paste my screenshots to be a bit clearer.

**MORE UPDATE here are the screenshots made by me switching from ios6 view mode to ios7 view mode**

[Screen 1](http://d.pr/i/t9j6)

[Screen 2](http://d.pr/i/tOxw)

[Screen 3](http://d.pr/i/MxFF)

[Screen 4](http://d.pr/i/2SDk)

[Screen 5](http://d.pr/i/EiSt)

[Screen 6](http://d.pr/i/uu2c)

[Screen 7](http://d.pr/i/7tG0)

[Screen 8](http://d.pr/i/nIao)

[Screen 9](http://d.pr/i/uXpl)

[Screen 10](http://d.pr/i/9S9b)

[Screen 11](http://d.pr/i/VPEs)

[Screen 12](http://d.pr/i/p8c5)

[Screen 13](http://d.pr/i/SIr)

[Screen 14](http://d.pr/i/YDo5)

[Screen 15](http://d.pr/i/RzVe)

[Screen 16](http://d.pr/i/WziI)

Comment: Have a read of the iOS 7 transition guide here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/AppearanceCustomization.html may give you a better incite into `iOS7` and how things work and appear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have a same issue, but was added by 64, it's bug of xcode5, for me helped turn off Top Bar in storyboadrd for controller, like that http://d.pr/i/MRtE

### UPDATED (from comment):

*there are some misunderstanding about this comment (in any way this comment isn't a solution of problem, but I will leave it here for now)*

i'm talking not about sdk bug, but for Xcode5 bug:
try to set some view controller in storyboard to such settings:

```
size -- freeform, 
status bar -- Light content, 
top bar -- opaque Navigation bar with prompt.
```

After that try to switch to other class than back to storyboard, make it few times and look at your vc's size

Comment: This 64 point should be the StatusBar (20 point) and the NavigarionBar (44point).

Comment: Sorry but -1 for indicating this is a bug. It isn't a bug at all. In `iOS7` the status bar isn't taken into consideration so things now appear behind the status bar this is part of Apples new flat UI. Think you might need to read the Apple docs on iOS7 transition guide https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/AppearanceCustomization.html

Comment: every time when i go in storyboard my viewcontroller increased on 64 points, are you kidding me it's not a bug? i do not say about working on device or simulator application, i'm talking about storyboard in xcode (maybe author have the same issue), my viewcontroller became about 3k height in a half an hour of working with storyboards

Comment: The 64 points is correct for how it should be. 20 points for the status bar and 44 points for your navigation bar. How is this a bug? Please explain. Have you read anything to do with iOS 7 such as the transition guide I have provided?

Comment: ok just try to set some view controller in storyboard to such settings: size -- freeform, status bar -- Light content, top bar -- opaque Navigation bar with prompt. After that try to switch to other class than back to storyboard, make it few times and look at your vc's size

Comment: i'm talking not about sdk bag, i'm talking about XCode bug

Comment: That isn't what you indicated in your answer at all. I have tested as you indicate and yes it does do this so yes that is a bug. But either way if you follow the users steps to reproduce this isn't the issue they are having at all. So my -1 remains.

Comment: yeah i reread what i wrote in post (updated it), and yes - it isn't related to question, sorry for this) no problem about -1)

Comment: I say Сергей Малетин got it right. I do understand the concept of switching the view from iOS6 to iOS7 back and forth increases the VC's height.

Answer (score 1):

This 20 point is the height of the StatusBar. On iOS 7 the ViewController's view is fullScreen sized, but on iOS 6 i's height is smaller with the stausBar. On iOS 7 the view's content is under the statusbar too.

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the section on [Bars and Bar Buttons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH8-SW1) under the [iOS 7 Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH15-SW1) you will see

> Because the status bar is transparent, the view behind it shows through. The style of the status bar refers to the appearance of its content, which includes items such as time, battery charge, and Wi-Fi signal. Use a UIStatusBarStyle constant to specify whether the status bar content should be dark (UIStatusBarStyleDefault) or light (UIStatusBarStyleLightContent):

So because of this the `UINavigationBar`, `UISearchBar` etc heights have increased from 44 points to 64 points in `iOS 7` see **table 5-1** for more information on **Treatment of resizable background images for bars at the top of the screen**

As another user has indicated in there answer that this is a bug and needs reporting I thought I would add this. **This is not a bug and doesn't need reporting** this is part of the new Flat UI design that Apple have decided to introduce.

For the whole lot on [iOS 7 Design resources check here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/design/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013289)